# Why does R need to be greater than 0 for the poles to lie inside $ C_{R} $?

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-integral-formula

I don't understand why R>1 is a condition for the two poles to lie inside the contour $ C_{R} $ ?

[image]

Comment: The two points $z_0 = e^{i\pi/4}$ and $z_1=e^{i3\pi/4}$ lie on the circle $C_1$ of radius $1$ centered on the origin. If $R>1$ then $C_R$ has larger radius than $C_1$ and so $z_0,z_1$ are inside $C_R$. But if $R<1$ then $C_R$ has smaller radius than $C_1$ so $z_0,z_1$ are outside $C_R$.

Comment: @LeeMosher much appreciated, thanks!